# Finding items in a javascript object consisting of complex nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

I need to find items in a javascript object which are in various arrays.  The arrays are in the nested javascript object.  I have implemented a way to get at the data I need but it seems very long winded with 4 nested for loops.

I realise I could use a for loop  to iterate thru the elements but that is not the prettiest way.  I have worked out how to use the filter function to access top level items that I am interested in, but struggling to work out how to filter on inner items.

In my code below, interesting_lines get appropriately populated.  The next stage is to create a list of all the elements with measurement.value.label of "fw" then print the measurement.value.value numbers.  How can I do that?

```
// lines crossed that we are interested in
let interest = ["Entry", "Exit"];

let lines = {"element":[{"element-id":2,"element-name":"line_2.1","sensor-type":"MULTI_SENSOR","data-type":"LINE","from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","resolution":"ONE_MINUTE","measurement":[{"from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","value":[{"value":0,"label":"fw"},{"value":0,"label":"bw"}]}]},{"element-id":3,"element-name":"line_2.2","sensor-type":"MULTI_SENSOR","data-type":"LINE","from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","resolution":"ONE_MINUTE","measurement":[{"from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","value":[{"value":1,"label":"fw"},{"value":0,"label":"bw"}]}]},{"element-id":1,"element-name":"Entry","sensor-type":"MULTI_SENSOR","data-type":"LINE","from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","resolution":"ONE_MINUTE","measurement":[{"from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","value":[{"value":1,"label":"fw"},{"value":0,"label":"bw"}]}]},{"element-id":0,"element-name":"Exit","sensor-type":"MULTI_SENSOR","data-type":"LINE","from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","resolution":"ONE_MINUTE","measurement":[{"from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","value":[{"value":0,"label":"fw"},{"value":0,"label":"bw"}]}]},{"element-id":4,"element-name":"line_2.3","sensor-type":"MULTI_SENSOR","data-type":"LINE","from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","resolution":"ONE_MINUTE","measurement":[{"from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","value":[{"value":0,"label":"fw"},{"value":0,"label":"bw"}]}]},{"element-id":5,"element-name":"line_2.4","sensor-type":"MULTI_SENSOR","data-type":"LINE","from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","resolution":"ONE_MINUTE","measurement":[{"from":"2018-05-08T08:59:00Z","to":"2018-05-08T09:00:00Z","value":[{"value":0,"label":"fw"},{"value":0,"label":"bw"}]}]}]};


console.log(`lines in collection=${lines.element.length}`);  // 6

// filter function on line name
function required_line(item) {
    for(var i = 0; i < interest.length; ++i) {
        if (item["element-name"] == interest[i]) {
            return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}

const interesting_lines = lines.element.filter(required_line);
console.log(`result of filter: ${JSON.stringify(interesting_lines)} `);

// filter out by label - eg fwd???
var morefiltered=interesting_lines.filter( function(element) { return element["measurement"]["value"]["label"] == "fw"; });
// above line fails - TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

console.log(`2nd level filter: ${JSON.stringify(morefiltered)} `);
```

My intended output would be:

```
forward line crossing numbers:
line name: Entry, value: 1
line name: Exit, value: 0
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: `measurement` and `value` are arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the `measurement` and `value` are arrays, you'll have to iterate though them,

```
const morefiltered=interesting_lines.filter( element => { 
    return element.measurement.filter(a => {
        return a.value.filter(b => {
            return b.label == "fw";
        })
    })
});
```

and create an empty array and fill it with matched values :

```js
// lines crossed that we are interested in
let interest = ["Entry", "Exit"];

let lines = {
  "element": [{
    "element-id": 2,
    "element-name": "line_2.1",
    "sensor-type": "MULTI_SENSOR",
    "data-type": "LINE",
    "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
    "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
    "resolution": "ONE_MINUTE",
    "measurement": [{
      "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
      "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
      "value": [{
        "value": 0,
        "label": "fw"
      }, {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "bw"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "element-id": 3,
    "element-name": "line_2.2",
    "sensor-type": "MULTI_SENSOR",
    "data-type": "LINE",
    "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
    "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
    "resolution": "ONE_MINUTE",
    "measurement": [{
      "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
      "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
      "value": [{
        "value": 1,
        "label": "fw"
      }, {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "bw"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "element-id": 1,
    "element-name": "Entry",
    "sensor-type": "MULTI_SENSOR",
    "data-type": "LINE",
    "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
    "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
    "resolution": "ONE_MINUTE",
    "measurement": [{
      "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
      "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
      "value": [{
        "value": 1,
        "label": "fw"
      }, {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "bw"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "element-id": 0,
    "element-name": "Exit",
    "sensor-type": "MULTI_SENSOR",
    "data-type": "LINE",
    "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
    "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
    "resolution": "ONE_MINUTE",
    "measurement": [{
      "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
      "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
      "value": [{
        "value": 0,
        "label": "fw"
      }, {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "bw"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "element-id": 4,
    "element-name": "line_2.3",
    "sensor-type": "MULTI_SENSOR",
    "data-type": "LINE",
    "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
    "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
    "resolution": "ONE_MINUTE",
    "measurement": [{
      "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
      "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
      "value": [{
        "value": 0,
        "label": "fw"
      }, {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "bw"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "element-id": 5,
    "element-name": "line_2.4",
    "sensor-type": "MULTI_SENSOR",
    "data-type": "LINE",
    "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
    "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
    "resolution": "ONE_MINUTE",
    "measurement": [{
      "from": "2018-05-08T08:59:00Z",
      "to": "2018-05-08T09:00:00Z",
      "value": [{
        "value": 0,
        "label": "fw"
      }, {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "bw"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};


// console.log(`lines in collection=${lines.element.length}`);  // 6

// filter function on line name
function required_line(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < interest.length; ++i) {
    if (item["element-name"] == interest[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

const interesting_lines = lines.element.filter(required_line);
//console.log(`result of filter: ${JSON.stringify(interesting_lines)} `);
let values = [];
// filter out by label - eg fwd >>>
const morefiltered = interesting_lines.filter(element => {
  return element.measurement.filter(a => {
    return a.value.filter(b => {
      if(b.label == "fw"){
        values.push({name : element["element-name"], value : b.value});
        return true;
      }
    })
  })
});

console.log('values : ', JSON.stringify(values))
console.log(`2nd level filter: ${JSON.stringify(morefiltered)} `);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is not great, so if you can change that, I would recommend that, which in turn would make your algorithm simpler.

I have tried to solve the problem for you using underscoreJS, but I'm not entirely sure this is what you want.

```
var myObjects = _.filter(lines.element, function(l){
  return _.any(interest, function(i){
    return l["element-name"] == i;
  });
});
```